# 日本語がおかしい：「回授与されました」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher

英語版を見ると単に「Awarded」となっています。

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher

Answer (score 1):

「Awarded」を「受け取りました」にしたらどうですか？

英語：

> Awarded X times

現在の日本語：

> X 回授与した

提案：

> X回受け取りました

（提案があれば、コメントで教えてください）

Comment: 「受け取りました」良いと思います。

Answer (score 0):

自分が眺めて受けた感想は、[文法の問題](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E7%99%BA_(%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95))です。

現状の「受け取りました」でも同様の違和感を覚えています。

ここからは個人の意見ですが、
一人称、二人称、三人称、当事者目線かそうでないかで日本語に違和感を感じました

一人称
私は「X回　獲得/受け取りま　した」
一度のみの場合
私は「　取得/獲得/受け取りま　した」

二人称
私の利用しているサイトが利用者数名に「X人に　授与/付与　しました」

三人称
前年度に引き続き「X回　獲得した/受け取った　」

というとても微妙な問題で違和感を覚えています。